# Какие технологии потребуются для реализации web-проекта? (делимся опытом, рекомендации, советы)

Tags: веб-программирование, php, html5, javascript

Доброго времени суток!
Есть примерно такая задача:
Имеется база данных **oracle\mysql** с некоторой информацией, по которой я должен строить **график 2D\3D**, разумеется на сайте.

Сам я так понимаю, что одним HTML5 тут дело не обойдется, ибо насколько мне известно это просто язык разметки, а **требуется как минимум <u>работа с базой данных</U>, <u>интерфейс</u>**.

В Web опыт крайне мизерный: простейший сайтик html+css в блокнотике:) Весь опыт главным образом накоплен в C++: олимпиадное движение, винапи, чуть-чуть OpenGL.

---

Подскажите пожалуйста: какие **технологии, языки** потребуются для реализации сего задания?
Если не трудно, то опишите вкратце для чего данная технология, хотя и сам могу это прочитать:)
Как много времени понадобится, чтобы разобраться с этим всем делом (мозги есть)?

Премного благодарен!:)

UPD1: написано основные HTML теги поддерживает, а подчеркивать не хочет:\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ес-но, SQL.
Обязательно javascript.
Хорошо бы какой-нибудь фрейморк, типа jquery.
желательно Canvas
базовое знание серверного языка. Сойдет и C++, но лучше что-то более распространенное(python, perl, php): меньше проблем с поиском хостинга будет.

Далее - качаете какой-нибудь бесплатный графпостроитель на JS и приспосабливаете под свои нужды.

Это самый простой путь.